# Problemas commit en Git

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

Hola Alguien sabe por que me aparece este error al momento de querer comparar 2 commits en git :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aunque ese parámetro del que se queja git podría ser un archivo, tiene toda la pinta de ser un ID. Eso es el ID de un commit? Si es eso, entonces es que ese ID no lo tiene git en su DB. Te falta hacer un fetch? De donde sacaste el ID?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder,  el tag lo saco haciendo un git log a un archivo que estoy trabajando y ahi me aparecen los commits.

Comment: Coloca la información completa del commit donde viste eso (cambia información como los correos o cualquier otra información confidencial de lo que salga en el commit).... pq si es una revisión a la que se le hizo squash en otro repositorio (o sea, viendolo en un comentario), podrías no tener ese commit en tu repositorio.

Comment: lo que estoy haciendo es un git diff para comparar las diferencias de ese archivo entre commits.

Comment: Cual archivo? Y x lo menos el commit del que git se está quejando, git no lo conoce.